# Whether usage of API key is secure?

Tags: api, security, flask

I am created API server using Flask where user provided (through usual web-interface) with personal API key. And then all requests sent to my server must provides this key (in header or as get/post parameter, it does not matter). For now server operates over HTTP (not HTTPS).

But I am wondering whether it secure? If somebody using wireshark or any other traffic sniffer get this address then he could send requests to my API as original owner.

I reviewed couple of resources provided API with apikey usage and found that many of them uses HTTP schema. If I turn HTTPS only and force clients to use HTTPS would it be enough to secure my application against malicious persons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS should be enough to secure flow of data over the network.

If you still want to support HTTP, then you can implement Limiting and Token-Expiry in your API.

By Limiting, you restrict the number of requests an API user can send within a particular timeframe.

By Token-Expiry, the user's API key expires after some time, and they can no longer use it. This means you'll have to implement token refresh in your codes.

Check out this [PyCon 2014 presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=px_vg9Far1Y&nohtml5=False) for better API implementations.
Find [Presentation source on GitHub](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/api-pycon2014)

Comment: Token-Expiry is interesting approach. Am I right that in this case I have to implement additional endpoint, for exmaple, called "login", so this endpoint must be accessed first with username/pass and return token to predefined timeframe? In this case I should think how to protect passing username/password overe network.

Comment: @AlexG.P. You are very right,  the token sent to the user should be an encrypted/serialized string containing user info, which you can decrypt to determine the user. Kindly accept my answer if it helps. 